# How to fetch data from mongo db using get method in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections

I have created two collections bear and bears in mongo db. I have defined bear collection in express code but it is accessing bears data. I am very confused now. (bear and bears have the same field(first_name and last_name) but values are different.

here is my code

app.js

```
router.get('/api/bears', (req, res) => {
   console.log("dfgdg",req.body)
    Bear.getBears((err, bear) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("fdggfd",bear);
        res.json(bear);
    });
});
```

models/bear.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const bearSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Bear = module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', bearSchema);


module.exports.getBears = (callback, limit) => {
    Bear.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

Can anyone know why bears data is fetched instead bear??

Comment: mongoose will create a collection on MongoDB using a plural name of the model name(default behavior). So your model bear is pointing to the bears collection. That's why you are getting data from bears collection.

Comment: By default your collection names will be appended with extra 's' and hence your bear collection will be bears. Check your database collections by `show collections`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code and had the same problem, I fixed it by adding a third parameter to `mongoose.model` specifies the name of the collection

```
const Bear = module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', bearSchema, 'bear');
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can use the third argument in `mongoose.model` for collection name like

```
//following will fetch the from bear collection
const Bear = module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', bearSchema, 'bear');


//following will fetch the from bears collection
const Bear = module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', bearSchema, 'bears');
```

**From the doc**

> When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose uses the model name.
>   If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name, use
>   mongoose.pluralize(), or set your schemas collection name option.

**Reference** https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model